# Не работают стили css не могу понять проблему всё подключено

Tags: html, css

Вот проблемный код

```css
.dub {
   display: flex;
   gap: 20px;
   flex-wrap: wrap;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dubs.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dub">
   <p><img src=""></p>
   <p><img src=""></p>
   <p><img src=""></p>
   <p><img src=""></p>
   <p><img src=""></p>
   <p><img src=""></p>
   <p><img src=""></p>
   <p><img src=""></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

По итогу стили не применяются

Comment: `dubs.css` и разметка хранятся в одной директории?

Comment: Всё у вас прекрасно применяется. По крайней мере в здешней песочнице. Вот только внутри контейнеров пусто (изображения без оных), потому вы ничего и не видите. Поставьте на время тестирования  в теги 'p' текст вместо изображений и всё заработает. Ну или всё же прикрепите настоящие src="/..". Или, как подсказывают выше, проверьте путь к таблице стилей.